# Display deactivated items in lookup column

Tags: custom-list, lookup-column

We have a list of projects. One column is named Status (a choise Active or Finished) One column is Active Projects (a calculated column which shows only the actieve projects) One column is named Relations, users can choose more than one related project (this is a look-up column which displayes only the active Projects).

When a project changes Status from Active to Finished it no longer displayes in the Relation column. Is it possible to display this project as a relation?

Users may not choose a finished project as a relation but once chosen while being active the relation should still be visible even though the project is Finished.